# Is using timestamp to initialize Date affected by timezone?

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing

My local machine timezone is `Asia/China`, UTC+8.

```js
new Date(1509692400000).toISOString() // output: 2017-11-03T07:00:00.000Z
```

When I change the timezone environment variable `export TZ=Europe/Amsterdam`, I got the same ISO string of the date.

```js
new Date(1509692400000).toISOString() // output: 2017-11-03T07:00:00.000Z
```

Does this mean using a timestamp to initialize `Date`, not affected by timezone?

So I can use this way to mock the Date when running the unit tests on different remote CI servers with different timezones.

Answer (score 2):

As says [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString), `toISOString()` method always returns timezone UTC-0. In my opinion, if you want to use date in unit tests, shared in unknown-location servers, then setup `Date` object as you did and check date using `toUTCString()` - [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toUTCString)